# Implementing Mongoose models

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new to mongoose, I've looked at a few tutorials and I am familiar with the types in mongoose, however am confused as to how I can model this:

I have a sensor node with the following attributes:
 1) node ID
 2) location

I have locations with the following attributes:
 1)Name of location
 2)List of node IDs at that location

I also need a readings model that has the following attributes:
 1) number of ticks : Int
 2) node ID (of the node this reading came from)

I can design simple models in mongoose, however there are relationships between all three of these models I want to define, and I'm not sure how I can model them so that they are connected, e.g. Node ID in readings refers so some ID in the node model